# Why does the query error appear in the console even after it has been handled? RTK Query + React

Tags: reactjs, redux, error-handling, rtk-query

This is my error handler :

```
export const onAuthQueryStartedErrorToast = async (
  _: any,
  { queryFulfilled }: any,
) => {
  try {
    await queryFulfilled;
  } catch (error) {
    const isError = error as AuthErrorType;

    if (isError.error.data) {
      toast.warn(defineMessage(isError.error.data.message));
    } else {
      toast.warn("some error occured");
    }
  }
};
```

And this is my endpoint and the query I want to handle

```
export const AuthService = baseApi.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => {
    return {
      authMe: builder.query<AuthMeResponseType, void>({
        query: () => ({
          url: "v1/auth/me",
          method: "GET",
        }),
        onQueryStarted: onAuthQueryStartedErrorToast,
        providesTags: ["Auth"],
      }), ... }
```

And the error handling works just as expected, I get the toast with the message, however the console error 401 is still there and I have no idea how to get rid of it. Seems like it logs the error into the console before the handler(if it makes sense). Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware of this is default browser behavior for network errors to be logged to the console and there is nothing you can do from your web page/application to change or prevent this. Seeing these logs doesn't necessarily mean something wasn't properly handled within the app.

What you can do, however, is to change in the console what you actually see. In other words, you can "filter" errors from the console.

In the browser's devtools you can change the logging level to remove errors from the logged output.

Examples:

- Chrome: Deselect "Verbose" which displays all output, and deselect "Errors" to not output error logs.

  [image]
- Safari: Select anything but "All" or any multi-select that includes "Errors".

  [image]

Other browsers should have similar settings.

**Note:** Changing these settings only affects *your* browser. Users of your page/app can, and will, still be able to configure their browser how they like and see the browser-generated logging.

Note also that this will hide ***all*** errors generated by the page, not just network errors, so be aware of this during development that you may need to reenable error logging later to see important information. Use at your discretion.

Answer (score 0):

*You can use onError callback in your query, so this callback allows you to prevent the default error behavior including console logging.*

```
onQueryStarted: onAuthQueryStartedErrorToast,
providesTags: ["Auth"],
onError: (error, { queryFulfilled }) => {
  const isError = error as AuthErrorType;

  if (isError.error.data) {
    toast.warn(defineMessage(isError.error.data.message));
  } else {
    toast.warn("some error occurred");
  }
  queryFulfilled.rejectWithValue(error);
},
```

})

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, however seems like query doesn't have onError method

Comment: That option doesn't exist in RTK Query.

Comment: yes, you are correct, so it's possible that the error is being logged before your handler is called. you can try global error interceptor to resolve this issue.